# Generating DDL from hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, database, hibernate-mapping

The following hibernate mapping file generates the java class and the DEPARTMENT table as expected but it doesn't create the DPT_TEACHERS table in the DB, why not ?

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.Department" table="DEPARTMENT">
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="subject" column="SUBJECT" type="string"/>

        <set name="teachers" table="DPT_TEACHERS">
            <key column="ID"/>
            <one-to-many class="hibernate.Teacher"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add property

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

with your database connection properties in your hibernate.cfg.xml to create schema automatically.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

 <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/Test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

table="DPT_TEACHERS" is not required. There is no need for another table to create a 1:N relationship. key column="ID" is confusing, it should be key column="TEACHER_ID" so it can be added in Teacher table as a 1:N relationship